# Why can't I decode an extrinsic created with the contracts tab in Polkadot JS apps?

Tags: polkadot-js, subxt, contracts

I am running the [substrate-contracts-node](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node) and using the contracts UI to interact with it in Polkadot JS Apps. The contract call is failing when I try using the UI, although the same call works from a `subxt` test program.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create smart contracts via the upload&deploy button. [image]
2. Call it's method via the UI.

Since my contract failed with `ContractTrapped`, I went to the events tab to view the extrinsic and it's parameters. Using this I:

1. Reproduced the contract and called it from a test program using `subxt`.
2. I verified that it passed without problem.
3. I copied the extrinsic hash from the original failed extrinsic [image]
4. I pasted it under the extrinsics tab to decode it. But it was **unable to decode the extrinsic**. [image]

Why is the contract extrinsic undecodable? I'm suspecting the extrinsic created from the frontend is way different than hand rolling it via subxt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You tried to decode a hash of the extrinsic, not the actual encoded extrinsic itself.

The "extrinsic hash" is a one-way `blake256(<extrinsic data>)` so it doesn't contain the decodable extrinsic data.

Comment: Ah that makes sense, thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

If submitted via subxt, if you view the specific block inside the apps UI, the extrinsic will be decoded - so you can compare one submitted in another blocks (via JS) to one submitted in a recent block (via subxt).

Since you copied the hash, I'm assuming you could see the extrinsic.

Alternatively, make a rpc query for that block and copy/paste the extrinsic response (hex string) into the UI to be decoded.